# Swift tie game in Tic Tac Toe

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I know there are a few of these Tic Tac Toe questions but the logic depends on the model used and my check for winner model seems to be different. Can I insert an else statement or if loop to check for a tie where I've commented ***at the bottom***? It seems with my model I can simply check if winner != letterX && letterO do a "Game is a Tie" alert. I have NO IDEA how to do this. Thanks

```
func fieldTapped(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let tappedField = recognizer.view as TTTImageView //


    if turn == "deviceA" || turn == "yourTurn"{
        tappedField.setPlayer(currentPlayer)
        let messageDict = ["field":tappedField.tag, "player":currentPlayer, "turnString":"deviceA"]

        let messageData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(messageDict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: nil)

        let data = messageData
        // do something with the returned data
        var error: NSError?
        appDelegate.mpcHandler.session.sendData(data, toPeers: appDelegate.mpcHandler.session.connectedPeers, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Unreliable, error:&error)

        if error != nil{
            println("error:\(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    checkResults()
    turn = "deviceB"
}

func setupField(){
    for index in 0...fields.count - 1{
        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "fieldTapped:")
        gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

        fields[index].addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

    }
}

func resetField(){
    for index in 0...fields.count - 1 {
        fields[index].image = nil
        fields[index].activated = false
        fields[index].player = ""
    }

    currentPlayer = "letterX"
}

@IBAction func newGame(sender: AnyObject) {
    resetField()

    let messageDict = ["string":"New Game"]

    let messageData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(messageDict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: nil)

    var error:NSError?

    appDelegate.mpcHandler.session.sendData(messageData, toPeers: appDelegate.mpcHandler.session.connectedPeers, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Reliable, error: &error)

    if error != nil{
        println("error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }


}




func checkResults(){
    var winner = ""

    if fields[0].player == "letterX" && fields[1].player == "letterX" && fields[2].player == "letterX"{
        winner = "letterX"
    }else if fields[0].player == "letterO" && fields[1].player == "letterO" && fields[2].player == "letterO"{
        winner = "letterO"
    }else if fields[3].player == "letterX" && fields[4].player == "letterX" && fields[5].player == "letterX"{
        winner = "letterX"
    }else if fields[3].player == "letterO" && fields[4].player == "letterO" && fields[5].player == "letterO"{
        winner = "letterO"
    }else if fields[6].player == "letterX" && fields[7].player == "letterX" && fields[8].player == "letterX"{
        winner = "letterX"
    }else if fields[6].player == "letterO" && fields[7].player == "letterO" && fields[8].player == "letterO"{
        winner = "letterO"
    }else if fields[0].player == "letterX" && fields[3].player == "letterX" && fields[6].player == "letterX"{
        winner = "letterX"
    }else if fields[0].player == "letterO" && fields[3].player == "letterO" && fields[6].player == "letterO"{
        winner = "letterO"
    }else if fields[1].player == "letterX" && fields[4].player == "letterX" && fields[7].player == "letterX"{
        winner = "letterX"
    }else if fields[1].player == "letterO" && fields[4].player == "letterO" && fields[7].player == "letterO"{
        winner = "letterO"
    }else if fields[2].player == "letterX" && fields[5].player == "letterX" && fields[8].player == "letterX"{
        winner = "letterX"
    }else if fields[2].player == "letterO" && fields[5].player == "letterO" && fields[8].player == "letterO"{
        winner = "letterO"
    }else if fields[0].player == "letterX" && fields[4].player == "letterX" && fields[8].player == "letterX"{
        winner = "letterX"
    }else if fields[0].player == "letterO" && fields[4].player == "letterO" && fields[8].player == "letterO"{
        winner = "letterO"
    }else if fields[2].player == "letterX" && fields[4].player == "letterX" && fields[6].player == "letterX"{
        winner = "letterX"
    }else if fields[2].player == "letterO" && fields[4].player == "letterO" && fields[6].player == "letterO"{
        winner = "letterO"
    }




    if winner != ""{
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Tic Tac Toe", message: "The winner is \(winner)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            self.resetField()
        }))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

if winner != "letterX" && "letterO"  {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Tic Tac Toe", message: "Tie Game", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    self.resetField()
    }))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: Don't use backticks for large blocks of code - simply indent by four spaces - you can select the block and tap the {} button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem you're having is that in the logic result of your test

```
winner != "letterX" && "letterO"
```

the equality operators == and != have precedence over the && logical and so it's is evaluated first this way:

```
winner != "letterX"
```

this will result in a logical true or false. Lets say it's true then the next part of the evaluation continues like this:

```
true && "letterO"
```

You can see what the problem is. There is an order of precedence for operators but when in doubt simply use parenthesis.

```
if ( ( winner != "letterX" ) && ( winner != "letterO" ) )
```

lets say winner is equal to "sdfds" this would evaluate to:

```
if ( ( true ) && ( true ) )
```

that makes it easier to follow and debug if needed.

========= ADDITIONAL ANSWER BASED ON THE Git CODE =======

I checked your Git and the problem you're having happens because the check in the other device's app can give a positive tie condition before a field from an incoming message is activated. I think that instead of adding more checks to that protocol there's an easy way to know if you're out of plays by keeping a number of plays counter that's incremented by either an own tap or a message from a tap in the other device and use it as the test.  That way when there is no winner and you've done all possible plays ( numberOfPlays >= 9 )then it's a tie.

Add this to the viewcontroller class

```
var turn:String!
var numberOfPlays = 0 // number of plays counter
```

add it here:

```
fields[field!].player = player
fields[field!].setPlayer(player!)
numberOfPlays++   // there was a tap in the other device
```

also here:

```
if turn == "deviceA" || turn == "yourTurn"{
  tappedField.setPlayer(currentPlayer)
  numberOfPlays++   // we tapped on our device
```

also in  resetField():

```
func resetField(){
    for index in 0...fields.count - 1 {
        //println(index, fields.count)
        fields[index].image = nil
        fields[index].activated = false
        fields[index].player = ""
    }
    numberOfPlays = 0   // rest counter to zero
    currentPlayer = "letterX"
}
```

and remove the whole func handlePotentialTie() from inside the checkResults() func and replace it for this instead

```
        if winner == "" {
            if numberOfPlays >= 9 {  //there is no winner and you've done all possible plays then it's a tie

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Tic Tac Toe", message: "Tie Game", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                    self.resetField()
                }))
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

               resetField() 

            }

        }
```

I started playing it and it's pretty cool.

Comment: ok the code worked. However the logic I implemented is incorrect. What's happening now is that as soon as player "letterX" or player "letterO" click the screen the game returns "Tie Game". lol What should I do?   Code is in my next comment. Why can't I post a big code block? How come only the first post is allowed to be long? I might have to provide an Imgur screenshot.

Comment: There might be some logic issue in your test for winner so first in your long if statement add `println( "winner = Letter?" )` where ? is O or X accordingly after all the `winner = Letter?` statements so you can see in real time in the debugger window what's being assigned.

Also I would change this one:  `if winner != ""` to:  `if ( ( winner == "letterX" ) || ( winner == "letterO" ) ) // then you have a winner` and this one:  `if winner != "letterX" && "letterO"` to:  `if winner == "" // then you passed through the long if else statement without assignments.`

Comment: Hi, Thanks I will try that. This check for potential tie code is actually old. Unfortunately with Stackoverflow's comment structures the newest comments often get missed. I previously posted an imgur link to my changes. http://i.imgur.com/ps6V9YZ.png.

Comment: @Ringo could you update the Git code you posted above to the latest?. Looking at it in code form helps because Xcode source check catches errors that could be missed just visually.

Comment: Yup here is a quick screen for brevity http://i.imgur.com/lAD421N.png  and here is the Git link. I pushed just now so all should be up to date. https://github.com/tysunmac/Tic-Tac-Toe

Comment: @Ringo I think you're missing that source code swift file from the screen shot in your Git files. Please check.

Comment: ...just did it, sorry.

Comment: Did that update for you? I pushed and committed but it still says "7 days ago" for some reason. Sorry, I'm a noob with all of this stuff so I'm still trying to figure out checkout, push and commit.

Comment: @Ringo no it didn't. I have no swift source that has what you posted in the screen shot. I have AppDelegate.swift, MPCHandler.swift, TTTImageView.swift and ViewController.swift. In none of those I can find any of the code seen in the screen shot you posted.

Comment: ok I'm not sure what's going on. If I want to send my changes I select either push or commit in Xcode right? I did that but it still says "7 days ago" on GitHub.

Comment: Changes are there. I think it just took a while for Git to update. Btw, Do I need to use the GitHub OS X app to send these changes? I clicked push and commit in Xcode but I'm not sure it worked. Then after I clicked 'sync' in the OS X GitHub app it seemed to update on Git.

Comment: Are you DigitalDeath on Git as well? I can add you as a Collaborator if it makes it easier. I'm not sure how people edit files that aren't theirs on Git.

Comment: @Ringo I took a look at the code. I found the reason for the problem you reported and changed the code and it works now. I updated the answer with the changes you could do to make it work.

Comment: Wow, it works flawlessly. I don't know how to thank you. You made it look so easy to fix. I really appreciate you taking the time to look at my code. I feel so much better now that I can see the results of my long hours. I'm a Stack noob so I can't even upvote you. But I won't forget. As soon as I hit 15 reputation I'm coming back here to upvote you.

Comment: @Ringo you can select and mark the checkmark right below the 0 with the two up-down triangles as this being the right answer so it's set as answered. [look at this image to see what I mean](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) and [this post that explains it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Done! p.s. I need a mentor/tutor. Have you ever thought of providing this service? I'd be willing to make Paypal contributions. Seriously. If it's something you'd consider email me.  accnts∆hotmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

at the bottom you have:

```
if winner != "letterX" && "letterO" {
    ...
}
```

try changing that to:

```
if winner != "letterX" && winner != "letterO" {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have pointed out, where you said `winner != "letterX" && "letterO"`, you need to say `winner != "letterX" && winner != "letterO"`. But you have some other problems with your code. You fail to discern the difference between a tie game and a game that's not over yet, which means you'll call the game a tie after the first move. Also, you've repeated strings all over the place and you're checking for wins in a very repetitive way. Both of these things are error-prone. Let's fix these problems.

We should define constants for the player strings, and for the board size:

```
class TicTacToeController {
    let X = "X"
    let O = "O"
    let boardSize = 3

    var fields: [Field]

    init() {
        fields = [Field](count: boardSize * boardSize, repeatedValue: Field())
    }
```

Why define a constant named `X` containing `"X"`? Because if we mistype `X` as `Y` somewhere, the compiler will report an error, but if we mistype `"X"` as `"Y"` somewhere, we'll have to figure out what's wrong at runtime.

In `checkResults`, we need to handle each of the four possible states of the game:

```
    func checkResults() {
        if handlePotentialWinForPlayer(X) { return }
        if handlePotentialWinForPlayer(O) { return }
        if handlePotentialTie() { return }
        switchTurnsAndContinueGame()
    }
```

To check that a player has won, we check for a winning row, a winning column, or a winning diagonal:

```
    func handlePotentialWinForPlayer(p: String) -> Bool {
        if playerHasWon(p) {
            // End game and announce that player p has won...
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    func playerHasWon(p: String) -> Bool {
        for i in 0..<boardSize {
            // Check column i
            if player(p, hasWonWithStartingIndex: i, stride: boardSize) { return true }
            // Check row i
            if player(p, hasWonWithStartingIndex: i * boardSize, stride: 1) { return true }
        }
        // Check diagonal shaped like \
        if player(p, hasWonWithStartingIndex: 0, stride: boardSize+1) { return true }
        // Check diagonal shaped like /
        if player(p, hasWonWithStartingIndex: boardSize-1, stride: boardSize-1) { return true }

        return false
    }
```

That relies on a helper function to actually check for a winning run:

```
    func player(player: String, hasWonWithStartingIndex start: Int, stride: Int) -> Bool {
        for i in 0..<boardSize {
            if fields[start + i * stride].player != player {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

To check for a tie, we see whether the board has any empty fields left. If all fields have been filled, it must be a tie (because we already checked for and didn't find a win):

```
    func handlePotentialTie() -> Bool {
        if contains(fields, { $0.player == "" }) {
            // An empty field: the game isn't over.
            return false
        } else {
            // No empty fields: the game is over and must be a tie.
            // End game and announce the tie.
            return true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Rob. Thanks for helping me out again. Actually the game is already finished and coded. All the logic works well even the peer connections for 2 player. The only problem is as you know the code for the tie game. I can't add your code because I've already successfully checked for winner etc. Would you or someone else mind taking a look at it on Git? The check for winner code is towards the bottom of the view controller file. I just need to add a check for tie function using the code that's already there. Thank you in advance. https://github.com/tysunmac/Tic-Tac-Toe

Comment: If you read through my answer, it should help you understand how to detect when the game isn't over. You can translate the concept to work in your existing code.

Comment: Ok so no errors or crashes but sort of strange behaviour when a field is clicked AFTER all fields are already full. Says player X or O (depending on who clicked the screen) won the game. Here's a screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/ps6V9YZ.png   and another  http://i.imgur.com/qf80NGR.jpg